# tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020)

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I installed the MacTex 2020, but still got this message. I dont understand what is local TeX Live and what is remote repository. I also read the related previous posts and tried to downgrade remote repository, but it didn't work. I still got the same message.

Comment: I got this message only when I use LaTex package "titletoc". If I don't use this package, everything works out smoothly.

Comment: can you show the first few lines of your .log file?

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.6.17)  28 APR 2020 08:56
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.

Comment: the last few lines:   
! LaTeX Error: File `titletoc.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.117 ^^M
          
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: ...

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: OK this means that your program is using your texlive2019 installation and not the one from mactex 2020. Can you check that mactex 2020 is in your path? What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: but I downloaded the 2020 version from: http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html. Anyway, how can I check my path?

Comment: I typed echo $PATH in the terminal and got: //anaconda3/bin://anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin